# Blender 2.91 menu highlighting and background is a half triangle with a half transparent triangle - how to turn off?

Tags: interface, customization, system

I just installed Blender 2.91 and now the menus all have triangles in the background with half of the menu and menu items highlighted by a triangle and the other triangular half of the menu is transparent. How do I turn it off? It's pretty awful to look at! I just want regular menu highlighting and backgrounds without the triangles and transparency.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this likely means your GPU is unsupported. Check here for a list of supported GPU's, and if yours is supported, update your drivers. If it isn't, you can still use 2.79. - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: That's so strange - what does the menu highlighting have to do with the GPU?  All my menus were fine in all the iterations of Blender 2.8x, and this just happened in 2.91.  It doesn't happen on any other software.  As far as processing goes - it's much more processing to do a transparency than a solid background.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what causes it, but I've seen it many times before (including on this site), and in all the cases (at least the ones I experienced), the GPU was the issue. Perhaps more specifically an OpenGL issue. Maybe 2.91 isn't playing nice with your drivers. Any chance you have a brand new (possibly AMD) GPU?

Comment: Thanks, weird.  It's a much older nVidia GeForce card on OSX 10.13.6.